# How to give a scene a static height of 500px using A-frame?

Tags: aframe

I'll create a website with HTML content mixed with WebVR content. For the WebVr partial I'll use A-frame. The VR partial I'll give a maximal height of 500px.

When the site is loaded, you can see the VR part and a small part of the content of the site. The VR part is not the same height of the window. It's a bit like this site: [Bowling Stones at Brussels](http://www.bowlingstones.be/bowling-brussel-bowlen).

The headline here is a normal video but we want to change that to a 360 video or image that can be viewed by using the gyroscope of the phone.

[image]

Below, I've written a test but the image is wrong scaled. Here you could see the [original image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/hamburgerjung/34705881091/in/pool-equirectangular/) of code example below or on [this fiddle](https://codepen.io/HPawelyn/pen/ybGmpV).

```css
/* reset A-frame's CSS */
.a-html,
.a-canvas {
    position: relative !important;
}

.a-body {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}

.a-canvas {
    height: 100% !important;
}

/* My css */
.vrcontent {
  height: 500px;
}

.calltoaction {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 500px;
}

.content {
  width: 900px;
  margin:m 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<div class="vrcontent">
  <a-scene embed>
    <a-assets>
      <img id="sky" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4248/34705881091_37b5cf2d28_o.jpg" alt="" />
    </a-assets>

    <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>
</div>

<!-- start test 1 -->

<div class="overlay">
  <button class="calltoaction">Click me!</button>
</div>

<!-- eide test 1 -->

<div class="content">
  <p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti animi aliquid architecto quibusdam ipsum, debitis dolor mollitia. Quidem, cumque quos porro doloribus iure dolore illum, qui rem asperiores unde laboriosam.</span>
    <span>Dolorum tempora quam eveniet ea recusandae deserunt, velit similique. Cum sunt rerum beatae officiis qui sed molestiae et ullam quasi, harum maxime vel, aspernatur quidem molestias. Provident quae illo harum?</span>
    <span>Sunt expedita, repellat saepe vel accusamus odio. Alias, obcaecati harum earum inventore asperiores quaerat, sit autem nostrum. Sunt illo numquam, temporibus pariatur optio nam, expedita necessitatibus aliquid nemo maxime nisi.</span>
    <span>Praesentium corporis, ea sunt asperiores, recusandae animi, rem doloribus, possimus cum laudantium libero. Maiores a, iusto aspernatur reiciendis ratione sunt nisi, rem, quasi temporibus ullam non. Neque repellat facilis illo.</span>
    <span>Quibusdam reiciendis sunt tempora fuga deleniti, molestias temporibus doloremque. Nam sed consequatur consectetur ut tempora a nesciunt, perspiciatis dolorem reprehenderit modi enim at veritatis, excepturi voluptate quod, voluptatibus voluptas. Cum.</span>
    <span>Debitis, nesciunt, repellat voluptatem sapiente incidunt quidem asperiores reprehenderit vero quisquam placeat sunt voluptatibus velit. Consectetur atque voluptates, repellendus facere sequi ea totam quia quis non incidunt. Soluta, aut, provident.</span>
    <span>Eos sequi itaque dolorem atque ex id maiores dolor eaque libero iste deserunt ea voluptate minima cum laboriosam, qui animi, fuga suscipit necessitatibus vero, autem blanditiis, totam nulla. Quo, et.</span>
    <span>Quisquam commodi voluptatum dolorem aspernatur, distinctio et ullam laborum laboriosam quo nisi, praesentium quaerat ab excepturi. Illum harum doloremque, accusantium, beatae culpa assumenda laboriosam, quos mollitia aperiam dolorem praesentium minus!</span>
    <span>Doloribus ducimus odit veritatis fuga excepturi repellat culpa possimus obcaecati mollitia, dicta, totam itaque ipsa dignissimos quisquam tenetur. Dolorum magnam ullam nobis libero, nisi blanditiis adipisci, atque tempore impedit quisquam.</span>
    <span>Similique, pariatur unde. Autem ipsum amet asperiores necessitatibus optio incidunt ducimus, fugit officiis excepturi, dolor repellat aspernatur pariatur quia deserunt explicabo adipisci. Officia nemo cupiditate reprehenderit ipsam corporis, quibusdam. Deserunt.</span>
    <span>Maiores sapiente ullam, nulla hic voluptas perferendis quam soluta praesentium reiciendis ex rerum repellat velit in nisi odio expedita doloribus laboriosam modi fugit numquam molestiae provident cum. Iste, quasi repellendus!</span>
    <span>Nesciunt molestiae vitae, non cum ad facilis adipisci ipsam perferendis ratione dolorum ipsa itaque possimus a hic molestias quas enim dignissimos ab maiores quos, tempore delectus. Ad deserunt sequi dicta!</span>
    <span>Aspernatur porro vitae numquam dolore consequuntur maiores. Iste commodi reiciendis facilis laboriosam pariatur error eveniet ratione laudantium. Fugit corrupti cumque vel ipsum mollitia pariatur nostrum velit, quis. Quam soluta, fugiat.</span>
    <span>Obcaecati suscipit cumque repellendus architecto consequatur dicta ducimus laborum tempora. Fuga animi esse eius. Perspiciatis ab perferendis unde exercitationem. Ex ad pariatur eum vero dolores, perferendis laboriosam necessitatibus veniam repudiandae.</span>
    <span>Tempora, aut vero sed omnis eveniet fuga exercitationem totam numquam perferendis. Labore repellat dignissimos quia. Dolorem, temporibus, veritatis. Officiis laborum, inventore sit voluptas molestiae illum deleniti voluptatem dolorem soluta nihil!</span>
    <span>Expedita soluta, iste tempora amet optio, quam impedit eos sit illum debitis animi, tempore necessitatibus ut modi itaque voluptatem earum odio dolores enim. Praesentium nemo laborum nisi excepturi vel obcaecati.</span>
    <span>Unde quod illo quasi laboriosam sunt cumque, debitis voluptate laudantium delectus magnam dolore voluptatem minima eum, harum suscipit nostrum officia nemo fuga quaerat dignissimos accusamus! Ducimus dolore amet tempora natus!</span>
    <span>Nemo necessitatibus architecto incidunt esse? Quisquam maiores unde doloribus illo, amet iusto assumenda, sint sequi laboriosam odit velit error explicabo ab. Quo et magnam non, assumenda numquam omnis sunt eum.</span>
    <span>Nihil temporibus, est dignissimos deserunt doloribus veniam quod. Dolorum magni maxime voluptatibus recusandae reiciendis, voluptas animi nam distinctio illo cumque dolore fugit veniam, ab, quibusdam deserunt iste? Quos, quae, aut!</span>
    <span>Ex ratione quisquam voluptas consectetur fugit optio, possimus nobis voluptatum minus fugiat. Dolorem, sequi totam. Dolores perferendis voluptatem obcaecati harum unde blanditiis enim in, nemo, deleniti accusantium, impedit molestiae animi!</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

The image looks like this:

[image]

But when I remove the width of the `.vrcontent` element, it looks normal.

So my question is can I set the height of the scene using this pseudo code?

```
<a-scene height="500">
    ...
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a-scene embed>` should be `<a-scene embedded>` https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/embedded.html